# How to remove the white lines surrounding a button appearing when I click it

Tags: vb.net, winforms

It works fine until I click it and pop up a file dialog box,and then white lines appears surrounding it.
I don't know how to remove these ugly lines.

[image: screen shot]

The only code is `openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()`.

It's a Button whose `FlatStyle` is `flat` and whose `BackgroundImage` is a `PNG` image.
After that the white lines appears, and if I click the Form it will disappear.

Comment: Try setting the border size of the button to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround is to set the Button `FlatAppearance.BorderColor` to its `Parent.BackColor`. It will *overwrite* the focus rectangle. The `MouseUp` event can be used to set the value, it will be raised before a new Window is opened (the `Control.Leave` event will never be raised):

```
Private Sub SomeButton_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles SomeButton.MouseUp
    Dim ctl As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    ctl.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = ctl.Parent.BackColor
End Sub
```

Using the `Control.Paint` event, we can also use the `Control.BackColor` property to paint the border, both with the [ControlPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.controlpaint?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.ControlPaint);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) class `DrawBorder` method (simpler than using the [ButtonRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer?view=netframework-4.7.2) class):

```
Private Sub SomeButton_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles SomeButton.Paint
    Dim ctl As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ctl.ClientRectangle, ctl.BackColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
End Sub
```

and painting the Control's border ourselves:
(Note that the `ClientRectangle` size must be shrinked, by 1 pixel, both in the `Width` and `Height` dimensions. This is by design).

```
Private Sub SomeButton_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles SomeButton.Paint
    Dim ctl As Control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    Dim r As Rectangle = ctl.ClientRectangle
    Using pen As Pen = New Pen(ctl.BackColor, 1)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, r.X, r.Y, r.Width - 1, r.Height - 1)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks so much the issue is fixed.It hit me that if the form has a colorful background image ,how to fix this issue?

Comment: Then you're left with the Paint event only. You can use the `Control.BackColor` as the color of the Border. I've added this information to the answer and modified the code accordingly.

Comment: If the Parent is a Form, remember to set the `Form.DoubleBuffered` property to `True`, if you haven't. Avoids flickering.