# Removing borders on flat buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, button

So I am using a button on my program, and when I use button1.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0; it works fine.

[image: Button Working]

But.. when I click on the desktop, it does this.

[image: Button Glitch]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Win Forms, WPF, a web page? What does VS-2019 have to do with it? Please tag this properly.

Comment: Try setting `FlatAppearence` to `Flat`.

Comment: 'Button' does not contain a definition for 'Flat' and no accessible extension method 'Flat' accepting a first argument of type 'Button' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

:(

Comment: @Oupitter which value has the property `FlatStyle`

Comment: [How to remove the white lines surrounding a button appearing when I click it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53867195/7444103). The code is VB.Net. If you need a *translation*, let me know.

Comment: I forgot about the C# (simplified) version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53784938/7444103).

Comment: @Mario Mitterbauer it is Flat

Comment: @Oupitter already tried `button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor=button1.Parent.BackColor` ?

Comment: No, and it fixed my issue. Thank you so much @Mario Mitterbauer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set (hardcode) the border color. With following code line the `button1` border color get the parent `Control` `BackColor`

`button1.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = button1.Parent.BackColor;`